# How do I solve multiple different BSODs?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have upgraded my PC and changed the motherboard, HDD, DVD, and the RAM (3 times) ... Now after installing the Windows 7 Ultimate, I get BSOD with different Errors each time ... Some times `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`, other times `BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO` I have analyzed the Dump file online at [OSR Online](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze) and got this result:

```
Debugging Details:
------------------


EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!memcpy+130
828888d0 8b448efc        mov     eax,dword ptr [esi+ecx*4-4]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  89f1b54c -- (.exr 0xffffffff89f1b54c)
ExceptionAddress: 828888d0 (nt!memcpy+0x00000130)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000000
Attempt to read from address 00000000

CONTEXT:  89f1b130 -- (.cxr 0xffffffff89f1b130)
eax=00000004 ebx=aa47def8 ecx=00000001 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=aa47def8
eip=828888d0 esp=89f1b614 ebp=89f1b61c iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010297
nt!memcpy+0x130:
828888d0 8b448efc        mov     eax,dword ptr [esi+ecx*4-4] ds:0023:00000000=????????
Resetting default scope

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_DEREFERENCE

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from 829b2718
Unable to read MiSystemVaType memory at 82992160
 00000000 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
klmouflt+60bf
9510e0bf ??              ???

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7E

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 828e3f97 to 828888d0

STACK_TEXT:  
89f1b61c 828e3f97 aa47def8 00000000 00000004 nt!memcpy+0x130
89f1b63c 9510e0bf 89f1b670 856aac78 847ce000 nt!RtlCopyUnicodeString+0x32
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
89f1b680 9510e172 847ce000 856aac78 00000000 klmouflt+0x60bf
89f1b698 829ed728 856aac78 847ce000 c000035f klmouflt+0x6172
89f1b6c4 82a88a14 bd0d5952 89f1b7bc 89f1b840 nt!IopLoadDriver+0x7ed
89f1b784 82a88a14 00000018 00000000 89f1b7f8 nt!CmOpenKey+0x264
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 nt!CmOpenKey+0x264


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  klmouflt+60bf

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: klmouflt

IMAGE_NAME:  klmouflt.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4ac61e77

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffffff89f1b130 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x7E_klmouflt+60bf

BUCKET_ID:  0x7E_klmouflt+60bf

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

I really need help. I have changed my RAM 3 times now and nothing happened. I`m starting to think that the motherboard is corrupted!!

Anyone got a clue why this is happening?

Comment: +1 Didn't know about OSR online! :O

Comment: Did you install all the drivers? Have you checked that any third-party software drivers are causing this? (eg. A bad behaving virus scanner could deny your memory from being read)

Comment: @TomWij: The only driver that I needed to install was the LAN which I downloaded from the Gigabyte Website (the manufacturer of my MB). Also I have installed the Kaspersky PURE trial version, MS Office 2007 and firefox. I have used these programs with another PC with either the same configuration or slightly different and the other PC is working fine till this day (more than 3 months). But this new PC has been giving BSOD for 4 days or more, and all the components have been bought from about 1 month ago.

Comment: About OSR Online, I just found it today when I was googling for an online dump analyzer :D

Comment: What about chipset and graphics drivers? Have you tried replacing the virus scan by a trial version of another virus scanner? Just trying to exclude software issues. If not, other hardware might be damaged... :-(

Comment: I am sure that there is no problem with the software I installed, except the LAN, I have downloaded it and haven`t used the motherboard DVD as I don`t have it now. When I bought it I had a problem with the RAM it was corrupted, and it has been replaced. The second one worked fine for a while and then started reading double capacity (a 2GB RAM was reading 4GB!), so it was replaced for the second time with a RAM of a different make, a samsung now. Is it possible that the motherboard is corrupted somehow?

Comment: PLUS, now I can`t access the Windows installed. I get BSOD before even the windows start!

Comment: Get rid of Kaspersky as soon as you possibly can. Then, if you have more than one RAM stick, remove all except one. Unplug your non-essential devices, including USB, DVD-ROM, modem, and NIC. Then see if Windows boots. Reconnect each of these devices one by one, with a reboot in between, and see what causes the failure. And yes, it is possible your motherboard is faulty.

Comment: @Randolph Potter: I have only 1 RAM Stick, DVD Writer and a HDD. Nothing more, everything else is on-board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was either a corrupted RAM or incompatible with the Motherboard. I bought another RAM, Kingston this time, and it worked well with me. Thanks all for the support.

Answer (score 3):

Given how much klmouflt.sys appears in your analysis, I would suspect it's Kaspersky, NOT a hardware issue.  Drivers are more often the problem than hardware.  I would suggest you look for an update to Kaspersky or uninstall it and see if the system becomes more stable.

Comment: I came here to say just this, your Kaspersky mouse filter is crashing your computer, uninstall Kaspersky, use the removal tool, and then reinstall.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see I could scroll down to go to the stack, well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Multiverse IT: your issue is a Kaspersky mouse filter driver, if you cannot boot your computer into Windows or Safe mode you will need to edit your registry.  The best way to do this is through another computer.  Remove your hard drive and attach it via USB enclosure to a different computer running Windows.

Open up regedit, highlight `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, and go to File -> Load Hive...

Find the registry file named SYSTEM on your computer's hard drive.  It is normally located `Windows\system32\config`  (on `F:` or wherever it got mounted.)

Next, type in the name you want to attach the hive as, I suggest `RemoteOS-HKLM-System`

Next, navigate to the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\RemoteOS-HKLM-System\Select` and look for the value named `Current`

Make a note of this value (it is usually `1`) and then go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\RemoteOS-HKLM-System\ControlSet00X` where X is the value you just made a note of, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\RemoteOS-HKLM-System\ControlSet00X\Control\Class\{4D36E96F-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`

The last part of key name is a `CLSID` the part that's different from its surroundings is the end of the first 8 characters `6F`, you'll know you're in the right place if the `(Default)` value is `Mice and other pointing devices`.

Next, check for values named `UpperFilters` and `LowerFilters` for `klmouflt` you should see it in the `UpperFilter` value along with `mouclass`.  Delete `klmouflt` but leave `mouclass`.

Next, highlight the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\RemoteOS-HKLM-System` and go to File -> Unload Hive.

Safely Eject your computer's hard drive from your friend's computer, reinstall the hard drive and then try to boot to Windows.  You ought to be able to at this point.

Next, remove Kaspersky via the Windows Add/Remove Programs utility `appwiz.cpl`.

Next, remove Kaspersky using the Kaspersky Removal tool.

Finally, reinstall Kaspersky or another antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run it in Safe Mode or apply a system restore? If you can, try the latter and see if you're able to boot up with out getting a BSOD.

Comment: nope, safe mode doesn`t start, and the system restore just crash!